# PRINT ALL JSON ATTRIBUTES VALUES IN PYTHON

Tags: python, json

```
{
    "OBJ": "ID",
    "UNQ": {
        "name": "ISD",
        "MANT": true
    },


    "features": [{
            "attributes": {
                "ID": 1,
                "PR": "X1",
                "CR": "Y1",
                "LU": 1,
                "CO": 15,
                "DE": null,
                "RE": 90
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "ID": 2,
                "PR": "X2",
                "CR": "Y2",
                "LU": 2,
                "CO": 23,
                "DE": null,
                "RE": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "ID": 3,
                "PR": "X3",
                "CR": "Y3",
                "LU": 3,
                "CO": 56,
                "DE": null,
                "RE": 6
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "ID": 4,
                "PR": "X4",
                "CR": "Y4",
                "LU": 4,
                "CO": null,
                "DE": 2,
                "RE": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "ID": 5,
                "PR": "X5",
                "CR": "Y5",
                "LU": 5,
                "CO": 34,
                "DE": null,
                "RE": null
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "ID": 6,
                "PR": "X6",
                "CR": "Y6",
                "LU": 6,
                "CO": 5,
                "DE": null,
                "RE": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "ID": 7,
                "PR": "X7",
                "CR": "Y7",
                "LU": 7,
                "CO": null,
                "DE": null,
                "RE": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**I want to print & store in a complex list py, all the Features => Attributes => ID,PR,CR,LU,CO,DE,RE => values.**
I'm on this since many hours and I didn't find a solution, hope you can help me. ‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
import json
            data = json.loads(string)
            i=0
            for a in data["features"][i]["attributes"]["value"]:
                print(a)
                i=i+1
```

Comment: there's no `true` and `null` in python instead they are `True` and `None`.

Comment: @PythonAddicted if `null` isn't part of python how do you expect to parse it? And every time it encounters `null` and `true` it raises error.

Comment: @Ch3steR Now I understood,  and how can i avoid it

Comment: @PythonAddicted While creating your json instead of add `null` add `None`. for `true` add `True`.

Comment: do you have a source or some links where i can see how to do this substitution?

Comment: @PythonAddicted check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion if your JSON is nested at an unknown level.

```
def recur(_json):
    if isinstance(_json,dict):
        for i in _json:
            print('key : {} value : {}'.format(i,_json[i]))
            if isinstance(_json[i],(dict,list)):
                recur(_json[i])
    elif isinstance(_json,list):
        for i in _json:
            if isinstance(i,(dict,list)):
                recur(i)
recur(json)
```

---

```
key : OBJ value : ID
key : UNQ value : {'name': 'ISD', 'MANT': True}
key : name value : ISD
key : MANT value : True
key : features value : [{'attributes': {'ID': 1, 'PR': 'X1', 'CR': 'Y1', 'LU': 1, 'CO': 15, 'DE': None, 'RE': 90}}, {'attributes': {'ID': 2, 'PR': 'X2', 'CR': 'Y2', 'LU': 2, 'CO': 23, 'DE': None, 'RE': 4}}, {'attributes': {'ID': 3, 'PR': 'X3', 'CR': 'Y3', 'LU': 3, 'CO': 56, 'DE': None, 'RE': 6}}, {'attributes': {'ID': 4, 'PR': 'X4', 'CR': 'Y4', 'LU': 4, 'CO': None, 'DE': 2, 'RE': 2}}, {'attributes': {'ID': 5, 'PR': 'X5', 'CR': 'Y5', 'LU': 5, 'CO': 34, 'DE': None, 'RE': None}}, {'attributes': {'ID': 6, 'PR': 'X6', 'CR': 'Y6', 'LU': 6, 'CO': 5, 'DE': None, 'RE': 2}}, {'attributes': {'ID': 7, 'PR': 'X7', 'CR': 'Y7', 'LU': 7, 'CO': None, 'DE': None, 'RE': 1}}]
key : attributes value : {'ID': 1, 'PR': 'X1', 'CR': 'Y1', 'LU': 1, 'CO': 15, 'DE': None, 'RE': 90}
key : ID value : 1
key : PR value : X1
key : CR value : Y1
key : LU value : 1
key : CO value : 15
key : DE value : None
key : RE value : 90
key : attributes value : {'ID': 2, 'PR': 'X2', 'CR': 'Y2', 'LU': 2, 'CO': 23, 'DE': None, 'RE': 4}
key : ID value : 2
key : PR value : X2
key : CR value : Y2
key : LU value : 2
key : CO value : 23
key : DE value : None
key : RE value : 4
key : attributes value : {'ID': 3, 'PR': 'X3', 'CR': 'Y3', 'LU': 3, 'CO': 56, 'DE': None, 'RE': 6}
key : ID value : 3
key : PR value : X3
key : CR value : Y3
key : LU value : 3
key : CO value : 56
key : DE value : None
key : RE value : 6
key : attributes value : {'ID': 4, 'PR': 'X4', 'CR': 'Y4', 'LU': 4, 'CO': None, 'DE': 2, 'RE': 2}
key : ID value : 4
key : PR value : X4
key : CR value : Y4
key : LU value : 4
key : CO value : None
key : DE value : 2
key : RE value : 2
key : attributes value : {'ID': 5, 'PR': 'X5', 'CR': 'Y5', 'LU': 5, 'CO': 34, 'DE': None, 'RE': None}
key : ID value : 5
key : PR value : X5
key : CR value : Y5
key : LU value : 5
key : CO value : 34
key : DE value : None
key : RE value : None
key : attributes value : {'ID': 6, 'PR': 'X6', 'CR': 'Y6', 'LU': 6, 'CO': 5, 'DE': None, 'RE': 2}
key : ID value : 6
key : PR value : X6
key : CR value : Y6
key : LU value : 6
key : CO value : 5
key : DE value : None
key : RE value : 2
key : attributes value : {'ID': 7, 'PR': 'X7', 'CR': 'Y7', 'LU': 7, 'CO': None, 'DE': None, 'RE': 1}
key : ID value : 7
key : PR value : X7
key : CR value : Y7
key : LU value : 7
key : CO value : None
key : DE value : None
key : RE value : 1
```

Comment: This returns to me: None

Comment: This will work once you have replace true with `True` and `null` with `None` .

Comment: i replaced all with string.replace but when i do json.loads(string) and try to print it nothing happears

Comment: r = r.replace("null", "None")      
            r = r.replace("true", "True")      
            r = r.replace("false", "False")      

            data = json.loads(r)
            
            print(recur(data))

Answer (score 0):

If you load json data to a python dictionary, you could access the values you want changing your for-loop to something like this:

```
for attr in data["features"]:
    for key, val in attr["attributes"].items():
        print(key, val)
```